# Img tag is not working with image name in language other than english

Tags: html

In my application, I uploaded an image which had name in Japanese language.

```
<img src ="somejapanesename.jpg" width="50" height="50"/>
```

Now when I try to display that image, it doesn't appear. It only appears when I give it a name in the English language . Is it possible to solve this problem ?

Edit : I have tried encodeUriComponent() and java's URLEncoder.encode() but it still shows 404 error in the console. 
 Please help

Comment: put the name in English...

Comment: The path to the file in the `src` attribute is technically an URL, so all non-Latin characters in it should be URL-encoded. You can use online tools like https://www.urlencoder.org/ for this.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn I have a relative path to the image. I am not able to imagine exactly how url encoder will work in my case. My image name in the directory is itself in japanese language .

Comment: I tried using encodeuricomponent() and java's URLEncoder.encode() but still it shows 404 error